# Sencha touch 2.0, android app keeps showing loading screen forever on certain devices

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I've finished writing my first Sencha app and released it in Android market place. This is basically for a conference being held in Metro Detroit Area next week. I'm also introducing Sencha in my company as a viable mobile option.

However once released into the market, it does not seem to load on certain devices. How to find out what is wrong on the device? It works great on desk top and also on certain android phones and nexus pad but does not load ( the user keeps seeing the loading page for ever) in certain other phones. I would like to know how to debug this issue? Does Sencha log the console log exceptions in logcat? Any help in this direction is highly 
appreciated!

I'm using Internet permissions to access twitter feed and google maps. Kind of guessing that the issue could be because of accessing Internet but how to find that out?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From experience, this is generally due to javascript errors before sencha has been properly set up. This can be missing functionality or include issues, picky parsers etc. There is no real good way to debug this more than to get ahold of an affected device and set `window.error = alert` before any other javascript is run.